# Can you find the time complexity of this piece of code?

Tags: time-complexity

I have tried to find but my answer doesn't match with the solution in the text.

Could anyone explain me to find the time complexity?

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        for (int j=i; j< i*i; j++)
            if (j%i == 0)
            {
                for (int k=0; k<j; k++)
                    printf("*");
            }
```

Comment: Yes. Can you? Show what you tried. Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: What *is* your answer and how did you come up with it? What is the solution in the text?

Comment: As luck would have it, this code measures its own complexity. Try it for different values of `n`, count stars, and see if you can find a correlation.

Comment: Solution in the text is O(n^5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Let `f(n)` be the number of operations aggregated from the outer loop,
- Let `g(n)` be the number of operations aggregated at the level of the first inner loop.
- Let `h(n)` be the number of operations performed at the level of the third (most inner) loop.

Looking at the most inner loop

```
for (int k=0; k<j; k++)
   printf("*");
```

We can say that `h(j) = j`.

Now, as `j` varies from `i` to `i*i`, the following values of `i` satisfy `i%j = 0`, i.e. `i` is a multiple of `j`:

```
j = 1.i
j = 2.i
j = 3.i
...
j = (i-1).i
```

So

```
g(i) = sum(j=i, j<i^2, h(j) if j%i=0, else 0)
     = h(i) + h(2.i) + ... + h((i-1).i)
     = i + 2.i + ... + (i-1).i
     = i.(1 + 2 + ... + i-1) = i.i.(i-1)/2
     = 0.5i^3   // dropped the term -0.5i^2 dominated by i^3 as i -> +Inf

=> f(n) = sum(i=0, i<n, g(i))
        = sum(i=0, i<n, 0.5i^3)
       <= sum(i=0, i<n, 0.5n^3)
       <= 0.5n^4

=> f(n) = O(n^4)
```

Comment: Thank you very much I had been stumped by  this problem

Answer (score 0):

### Could anyone explain me how to find the time complexity?

A posted claim of cited **`O( N^5 )`** was not supported by experimental data.
[image]
[image: a live-GUI for observed data]

Best start with experimentation on low scale:

```
for (         int aScaleOfBigO_N  =          1;
                  aScaleOfBigO_N <  2147483646;
                  aScaleOfBigO_N *=          2
                  ){        
    printf( "START: running experiment for a scale of N( %d ) produces this:\n",
                  aScaleOfBigO_N
                  );
    int letsAlsoExplicitlyCountTheVisits = 0;
    for (     int i = 0; i <  aScaleOfBigO_N; i++ )
        for ( int j = i; j <  i*i;            j++ )
            if (  j % i == 0 )
            {
                for ( int k = 0; k < j; k++ )
                {
                 // printf( "*" );                       // avoid devastating UI
                    letsAlsoExplicitlyCountTheVisits++;
                }
            }
    printf( "  END: running experiment visits this many( %d ) times the code\n",
                   letsAlsoExplicitlyCountTheVisits
                   );
}
```

Having collected some reasonably large amount of datapoints `( N, countedVisits )`, your next step may be to fit the observed datapoints and formulate the best matching **`O( f(N) )`** function of **`N`**.

That can go this simple.

```
START: running experiment for a scale of N(           1 )
  END: running experiment visits this many(           0 ) times the code.
START: running experiment for a scale of N(           2 )
  END: running experiment visits this many(           0 ) times the code.
START: running experiment for a scale of N(           4 )
  END: running experiment visits this many(          11 ) times the code.
START: running experiment for a scale of N(           8 )
  END: running experiment visits this many(         322 ) times the code.
START: running experiment for a scale of N(          16 )
  END: running experiment visits this many(        6580 ) times the code.
START: running experiment for a scale of N(          32 )
  END: running experiment visits this many(      117800 ) times the code.
START: running experiment for a scale of N(          64 )
  END: running experiment visits this many(     1989456 ) times the code.
START: running experiment for a scale of N(         128 )
  END: running experiment visits this many(    32686752 ) times the code.
START: running experiment for a scale of N(         256 )
  END: running experiment visits this many(   529904960 ) times the code.
START: running experiment for a scale of N(         512 )
  END: running experiment visits this many(  8534108800 ) times the code.
START: running experiment for a scale of N(        1024 )
  END: running experiment visits this many(136991954176 ) times the code.
START: running experiment for a scale of N(        2048 )
...
```

[Experimental data show about this **algorithm time-complexity** behaviour in-vivo:](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fymzzatgsi)